# Is there a limit to the number of File and Change watches for Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a limit on the number of watches Google allows?

Example:

```
drive
    .changes()
    .watch(channelBuilder().build())
    .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

No openly declared quota limits but it is mentioned that  [notification channel has expiration time](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#renewing-notification-channels).

Comment: Yep. The lack of documentation is why I ask.